# Setar cor default do textview no Android

Tags: android

Tenho um custom TextView, atualmente ele seta a cor do texto para branco, porém, eu queria que essa fosse a cor default, ou seja, que fosse escolhido branco caso não seja setado uma cor com textColor no xml, como fazer isso?

xml: (eu tentei setar textColor diretamente, porém, ele acaba setando branco, por causa do Java)

```
<com.app.customview.DefaultTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/especifico_label"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Java:

```
public class DefaultTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    private boolean isLight = false;

    public DefaultTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont();
    }

    public DefaultTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setAttr(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }

    public DefaultTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setAttr(context, attrs);
        setFont();
    }

    private void setAttr(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Font, 0, 0);
        isLight = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.Font_isLight, false);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            String tf;

            if(getTypeface()!=null) {
                switch (getTypeface().getStyle()) {
                    case Typeface.ITALIC:
                        tf = "fonts/segoeuii.ttf";
                        break;
                    default:
                        tf = "fonts/segoeui.ttf";
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                tf = "fonts/segoeui.ttf";
            }

            if(isLight) {
                tf = "fonts/segoeuil.ttf";
            }

            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), tf));
            setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se não me engano, por herdar de AppCompatTextView, ele vai pegar do tema automaticamente.

Comment: Já tentou remover setTextColor(Color.WHITE); ?! Hehe

Comment: @white, eu quero que ele fique branco por default...

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, o tema que estou usando deixa a fonte preta, não posso alterar isso no tema, tem que ser no customview mesmo

Comment: O que quero é: Que somente nesse textview, se eu não setar o textColor no xml dele, que a fonte fique branca, se eu setar, que a fonte fique da cor do que eu setei... Não posso alterar nada no tema, tem que ser apenas nesse customview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta apenas pegar o valor que foi (ou não) definido no textColor, se ele for nulo (nenhuma cor foi definida no XML), então sete a cor branca.

```
color = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textColor");

if(color==null) {
   setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```